# Where do the keys in the params array come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This question has been asked before, but this is a more specific instance.

In the Ruby on Rails "Getting Started" [ http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html ] web page, they're teaching you how to make a simple blog. I'm following most of it, but I do not get where this :article_id key value is coming from:

```
def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    ...some other stuff...
end
```

This is located in the commentsController of the web app. All article related coding is in the articlesController.

Is the underscore an indicator to the class the id belongs to? Meaning does this key value first find the article params array and then the id all by itself? Like as a feature of RoR? Or is the symbol just being put there for teaching purposes and does not ACTUALLY refer to anything?

If it is the latter case, how would you know the key value to use?

GET data is shown in the URL, but how would you set that to know what it is before ever calling up the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `routes.rb` defines routes, the matched route may have variable segments in it, and the variable segments are made available to you via the `params` hash in your controller.

If you're using `params[:article_id]`, the route that lead you to that action would have contained something like:

```
 /articles/:article_id
```

`params` will also contain any values passed along via the query string or form data, but as far as looking up records by their ID, the ID is usually a component of the URL.

> Is the underscore an indicator to the class the id belongs to?

No, it's simply part of the name.

> If it is the latter case, how would you know the key value to use?

Because you define the key to use in your routes file.

Comment: "The t.references line creates an integer column called article_id, an index for it, and a foreign key constraint that points to the id column of the articles table."read on the page.

Comment: @RM3 Migrations, foreign keys, columns and tables are all completely irrelevant here. This is a question about routing and the `params` hash, these things have nothing to do with your models or the layout of your database.

Comment: so in `/articles/:article_id` is the symbol there just a stand in? So if I used `:my_id` without creating or changing any routes, would I get the same result?

My confusion is that  all the routes in this walkthrough for articles have been `/article/:id` not `/:article_id`.

Comment: No, of course not. As I said, it's **all about** the routes. If you wanted to use `:my_id`, you would need a route defined using `/articles/:my_id`. If your routes use `/article/:id`, then you need to look at `params[:id]` for the value passed in via the URL.

Comment: A pretty simple way to think about it is that routes are somewhat like regular expressions with named matches. You could for example declare a route as: `get '/secrets/:foo/:bar/:baz', to: 'secrets#show'` and `/secrets/1/2/3` would give you the params `{ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }`. Rails does not care what you call the segments - but there are [strong conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).